# Spring Tool Suite not "Spring" in create New

Tags: java, eclipse, sts

When creating a new one, I do not see a Spring entry.
Please help me fix the error!.
Thanks all.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there is no Spring project type in Spring Initializr. To create a non spring boot project through eclipse just create a new maven project and select the spring-mvc archetype.